# Google Sheets Query: Adding Arithmetic Sequence Creating #N/A

Tags: google-sheets

I have this:

```
=query(Data, "SELECT A, B, sum(E), avg(D), sum(D), sum(F), sum(D)-sum(F) GROUP BY B, A ORDER BY A asc LABEL sum(E) 'Total Daily QTY', sum(D) 'Gross Daily Sales', sum(F) 'Daily Promotion Discounts', sum(D)-sum(F) 'Daily Gross Profit'")
```

I need to add one more column to the query with this format:

```
(sum(D)-sum(F))/sum(E)
```

Which gives me this:

```
=query(Data, "SELECT A, B, sum(E), avg(D), sum(D), sum(F), sum(D)-sum(F), (sum(D)-sum(F))/sum(E) GROUP BY B, A ORDER BY A asc LABEL sum(E) 'Total Daily QTY', sum(D) 'Gross Daily Sales', sum(F) 'Daily Promotion Discounts', sum(D)-sum(F) 'Daily Gross Profit'")
```

However, the result is #N/A. I'm not sure if it's creating a sort of circular reference and causing it to break? I tried separating it into an arraryformula, but couldn't get that to work properly either.

Can someone tell me how to get that added column in there correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Sheets bug. The query throws an unexplained "#N/A" error if the expression `sum(D)-sum(F)` appears twice: by itself and as a part of another formula. A simplified example:

```
=query(A:F, "select sum(D)-sum(F), (sum(D)-sum(F))/sum(E)")
```

throws an error but `=query(A:F, "select sum(C)-sum(F), (sum(D)-sum(F))/sum(E)")` (where I changed the first expression) works fine.  I think the software tries to optimize the execution by reusing previous data, and something goes wrong with that.

Workaround: change one of two formulas so that it doesn't look like one is a part of another. Adding `0+` at the beginning is enough for that:

```
=query(A:F, "select sum(D)-sum(F), (0+sum(D)-sum(F))/sum(E)")
```

and

```
=query(A:F, "select 0+sum(D)-sum(F), (sum(D)-sum(F))/sum(E)")
```

both work. (Don't add 0 in both places, however - then the second formula again has a part of the first, and we are back to #N/A)